# Calloc is returning an address that causes my program to segfault

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

So to start out this is the weirdest error I have ever seen. I have no idea whats going on. Any help anyone can lend on what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

I am writing a C program that reads a file into dynamically allocated chunks and performs various operations on those chunks (encryption/decryption/MACing etc...) When I run it on certain (larger?) files it segfaults. I figured I must be stepping on memory some where or not allocating it correctly. So I ran it in valgrind to try and figure out whats going on and the problem goes away. Valgrind reports no errors and the program doesn't segfault and works as intended.

```
normal run
./threefizer -e -p 1234567 new_name.docx
...
[1]    25017 segmentation fault  ./threefizer -e -p 1234567 new_name.docx

valgrind run
valgrind ./threefizer -e -p 1234567 new_name.docx
==25238== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25238== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25238== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25238== Command: ./threefizer -e -p 1234567 new_name.docx
==25238== 
...
Threefizer operation complete
==25238== 
==25238== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25238==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25238==   total heap usage: 25 allocs, 25 frees, 977,995 bytes allocated
==25238== 
==25238== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25238== 
==25238== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25238== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Whats going on here? I've seen valgrind prevent segfaults before just because it allocates memory differently inside its own vm. But always when I have had this happen before valgrind reports at least 1 error of some sort.

Digging deeper with gdb I found that the segfault is always happening when my program is trying to modify the contents of a chunk that was populated from a file read.

My file read function looks like this anybody see anything wrong here? Functionally it seems fine.

```
uint8_t* readBlock(const uint64_t data_size, const FILE* read)
{
    pdebug("readBlock()\n");
    if(ferror(read))
    {
        fclose(read);
        perror("Error reading block\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    const uint8_t* data = calloc(data_size, sizeof(uint8_t));
    const uint64_t size = fread(data, sizeof(uint8_t), data_size, read);

    if(ferror(read))
    {
        fclose(read);
        perror("Error reading block\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if(size == data_size)
    {
        return data;
    }

    perror("Unable to read requested number of bytes\n");
    free(data);
    return NULL;
}
```

A gdb session showing the read that is causing my program to segfault.

```
***Before read***
queueFile()
Breakpoint 1, queueFile (args=0x7fffffffe460, out=0x62c030)
at controller.c:172
//this is where the data is being read and allocated
172                       data_chunk->data = pad(readBlock(orig_file_size, read),
(gdb) print data_chunk->data
$1 = (uint64_t *) 0x0 //the brand new pointer is null as it should be with nothing allocated

***After read***
(gdb) next
readBlock()
176                       data_chunk->data_size = getPadSize(orig_file_size, args>state_size);
(gdb) print data_chunk->data
$4 = (uint64_t *) 0xfffffffff7ee7010 //why is this memory address so big?
(gdb) print data_chunk->data[0]
Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffff7ee7010 //can't access memory WTF?
//When this pointer is getting passed to anything else that attempts to access or modify it then the program segfaults
```

When the program tries to do anything with the data from readBlock() it segfaults. In this case its trying to encrypt it.

```
***Interestingly the address that is causing the program to segfault is 12 hex digits instead of the regular 6 why?***
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402413 in cbc512Encrypt (key=0x62be78 <runThreefizer.tf_key>, 
iv=0x62c2b0, plain_text=0xfffffffff7ee7010, num_blocks=7611) at cbc.c:206
206     plain_text[0] ^= iv[0]; plain_text[1] ^= iv[1]; plain_text[2] ^= iv[2]; plain_text[3] ^= iv[3];
```

With gdb when I try to access the same memory inside readBlock() I can access it just fine and it contains the proper contents of the file it is reading.

```
***GDB session showing the readBlock() that runs before segfault***
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
readBlock()

Breakpoint 2, readBlock (data_size=487073, read=0x62c360) at fileIO.c:40
40          return data;
(gdb) print data
$7 = (uint8_t *) 0x7ffff7f5e010 "PK\003\004\024" //again whats with the giant memory address all the other ones are only 6 hex digits
(gdb) print size
$8 = 487073
(gdb) print data[0] //as you can see we can access the data just fine and its contents correspond to the first 8 characters of the file that was read
$9 = 80 'P'
(gdb) print data[1]
$10 = 75 'K'
(gdb) print data[2]
$11 = 3 '\003'
(gdb) print data[3]
$12 = 4 '\004'
(gdb) print data[4]
$13 = 20 '\024'
(gdb) print data[5]
$14 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) print data[6]
$15 = 6 '\006'
(gdb) print data[7]
$16 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) 

***The same memory address is inaccessible from the function that calls readBlock()***
(gdb) break controller.c:173
Breakpoint 3 at 0x4038fa: file controller.c, line 173.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, queueFile (args=0x7fffffffe460, out=0x62c030)
at controller.c:176
176                       data_chunk->data_size = getPadSize(orig_file_size, args->state_size);
(gdb) print data_chunk->data
$17 = (uint64_t *) 0xfffffffff7ee7010 //this is the same address as data in readBlock() and also returned by readBlock()
(gdb) print data_chunk->data[0] 
Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffff7ee7010 //WHY NOT!?
```

So there you have it anybody have any idea whats going on?

Comment: Are you sure `calloc` succeeded?

Comment: Dedpulicator: I assume that is a rhetorical question, since the answer is pretty clear from the code.

Comment: You are showing us a GDB session that involves code you haven't shown us.

Comment: I believe it's an error to make `FILE` const since `fread` will modify it. (Although this seems unlikely to be the source of your troubles.) `data` shouldn't be const either. In general, none of your `const`s are particularly useful.

Comment: Some other code could be messing up the heap.

Comment: It shouldn't be the cause of your crash, but you pass `const FILE *read` into your function, but then pass that pointer to functions (such as `fclose()`) that take `FILE *` and not `const FILE *`.  You should be getting compilation warnings from that.  If you're ignoring those warnings, what else are you ignoring?  (If you aren't getting those warnings, you need to fix your compilation flags so that you do, and then fix your code so that you don't!)

Comment: The hex digits are so big because it's 64 bits. Seems obvious.

Comment: Can I hazard a guess? Where you call `readBlock()` did you make sure you including a prototype of `readBlock`?  The reason I ask is that inside of `readBlock`, your `data` seems to have an address of `0x7ffff7f5e010` but in the caller it seems to have changed to something like `0xfffffffff7ee7010`.  That could happen if the caller thinks that `readBlock` is returning an int (i.e. no prototype).

Comment: Good catch man. It ended up being a function that didn't have its prototype defined in the file that was using it. Although in the end it wasn't readBlock().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I hazard a guess? Where you call `readBlock()` did you make sure you included a prototype of `readBlock`? The reason I ask is that inside of `readBlock`, your `data` seems to have an address of `0x7ffff7f5e010` but in the caller it seems to have changed to something like `0xfffffffff7ee7010`.  That could happen if the caller thinks that readBlock is returning an int (i.e. no prototype).

I copied this from my comment since it solved your problem.  By the way, +1 for being one of the few people that uses a debugger and tries to isolate their problem with it.